# HOW TO FIX IT? AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-lab, image-preprocessing

```
    import numpy as np
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    
    
    %matplotlib inline
    
    
    
    path = './test/paper2.png'
    
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_test = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    
    classes = model.predict(img_test, batch_size=10)
    
    print(classes)
    paper, rock, scissors = classes[0]
    
    if paper==1.:
        print('paper')
    elif rock==1.:
        print('rock')
    else:
        print('scissors')
```

output :

---

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'
```

when I try to run. What does the error mean and how can I fix it?
help guys :)
I'm trying to learn
I don't know anymore which one is wrong

Comment: Try `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image` instead as mentioned here @Almaz Fazulzyanov

Answer (score 25):

Replace:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

for:

```
import keras.utils as image
```

Answer (score 18):

I'm facing the same problem today.
You can try using tensorflow 2.8.0 to fix it or try `tf.keras.utils.load_img` instead of `image.load_img`.

Answer (score 3):

I too had this and fixed

changes in import

1. "**from keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array instead**" of "**from keras.preprocessing import image**"

and
change

1. "**img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))**" to "l**oad_img(path, target_size=(150,150))**"
2. "**x = image.img_to_array(img)**"  to  "**x = img_to_array(img)**"

Comment: Could you share the keras version you're working with for reference? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I also face the same error.
I used `from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array`  and it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

change this

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('$PATH', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image =  image.img_to_array(test_image)
```

To this

```
from keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array
test_image = load_img('$PATH', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = img_to_array(test_image)
```

reff :- https://keras.io/api/data_loading/image/

Source :- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/utils/image_utils.py#L364

Answer (score 2):

The "AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'" occurs because the keras preprocessing API has been deprecated. To solve the error, import the load_img() function from tensorflow.keras.utils.load_img.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this first

```py
from keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array
```

Then use load image like this

```py
train_image = []

# ...

# Assume `train` is each batch X output in the form of dictionary
for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
    img = load_img('path to folder' + train['Name'][i], target_size=(400, 400, 3))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    train_image.append(img)

X = np.array(train_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.

To resolve this error, you can try importing the load_img function from the tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image module instead of the keras.preprocessing.image module. You can modify your code to include the following import statement :

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

there is no 'load_img'
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py

I suppose you trying to use load_img of keras.utils.image_utils

Comment: It looks to be in the documentation: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/? Any idea why the documentation is wrong?

Comment: documentations says
`import tf.keras.preprocessing.image` instead `keras.preprocessing.image`

Answer (score 0):

use `keras.utils.load_img`

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

image = keras.utils.load_img('path_to_image', target_size=(img_size, img_size))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added 'tensorflow.' infront of the keras like 'tensorflow.keras.' and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first import

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
```

then

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar error

```
module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'load_img'
```

and I had this import statement first

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

then I added utils so that

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras.utils as image
```

and then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and added:

import keras.utils as image

and its worked

Comment: This is already covered in existing answers. Please don't repeat answers or add "thank you" as an answer.